# Page goes in a buffer state after file uploads using multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I am uploading a file to a temp directory and after I click submit to upload my file, my page stays in a buffering state. I'm bit of a noob to node so any help is greatly appreciated. I'll add, the file uploads fine and the web app works fine while its in the "buffer state" its just a little annoying. It gives an open tio press esc to cancle or click to stop it.
My code is as follows

```html
<div class="button-wrap">
   <form action="/public/index.html" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
   method="POST">
   <label class="button" for="upload">Upload File</label>
   <input id="upload" name="filetoupload" type="file">
</div>
```

```js
var fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, './public/temp')
},
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '--' +file.originalname)
}
});

var upload = multer({ storage: fileStorage })

app.post('/public/index.html', upload.single('filetoupload'), (req, res)=>{
console.log(req, fileStorage);
// res.send('File uploaded');
});
```

Comment: Well, you need to actually send a respone, otherwise the request hangs. Looks like you already had it - what happens if you uncomment `res.send(..)` ?

Comment: @eol Ahh I see. Is there a way to have a response that doesn't interrupt the webpage with a message etc.?

Comment: If you mean ending the response without sending any response body, you can do e.g.:
`res.status(204).end();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually send a response. If you don't need/want to send a response body, you can do e.g.:

```
app.post('/public/index.html', upload.single('filetoupload'), (req, res)=>{
  res.status(204).end();
});
```